# msbuild does not find target (.csproj) to build on jenkins

Tags: jenkins, build, msbuild

I am trying to build a solution like this in Jenkins:

```
Build a Visual studio project or solution using MSBuild

msbuild version: msbuild5.0 x86
msbuild build file: myproyect.sln
command line arguments:/p:DeployOnBuild=true 
/p:PublishProfile=C:\PUBLISHING_PROFILES\FIRECOM_LOCAL.pubxml 
/p:FrameworkPathOverride="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319" 
/p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0
/target:MODELS\EntityModel;Common;NotificationLib;AccessLib;
       RemappLib;MODELS\FireWeatherModel;MODELS\EResponseWeatherModel;
       EResponseLib;FISLib;MODELS\LightningModel;MODELS\ResourceTrackingModel;
       ERESPONSEClient_myclient
```

All targets compile except the last one (ERESPONSEClient_myclient) which Jenkins does not find it (but it is in the workspace)

This is the error:

```
C:\Jenkins\jobs\ERESPONSE_CORE\workspace\MODELS\ResourceTrackingModel\ResourceTrackingModel.csproj
: error MSB4057: The target "ERESPONSEClient_myclient" does not exists in the project.
```

thank you in advance for your valuable help.

Comment: The error message is clear, it is telling that project "ERESPONSEClient_myclient" does not exists. Pls correct the path to this project. And also share the folder structure in Jenkins workspace.

Comment: ERESPONSEClient_myclient is in the workspace exactly like the others projects. But I have de solution: I had to do this step in two. One step with all projects except ERESPONSEClient_myclient and another step with ERESPONSEClient_myclient. Now it is working. Thanks Suresh, I am going to continue with the next error :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution:

step 1:

```
Build a Visual studio project or solution using MSBuild

msbuild version: msbuild5.0 x86
msbuild build file: myproyect.sln
command line arguments:
/p:DeployOnBuild=true 
/p:PublishProfile=C:\PUBLISHING_PROFILES\FIRECOM_LOCAL.pubxml 
/p:FrameworkPathOverride="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319" 
/p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0
/target:MODELS\EntityModel;Common;NotificationLib;AccessLib;
       RemappLib;MODELS\FireWeatherModel;MODELS\EResponseWeatherModel;
       EResponseLib;FISLib;MODELS\LightningModel;MODELS\ResourceTrackingModel;
```

Step 2:

```
Build a Visual studio project or solution using MSBuild

msbuild version: msbuild5.0 x86
msbuild build file:  ERESPONSEClient_myclient.csproj
command line arguments:
/p:DeployOnBuild=true 
/p:PublishProfile=C:\PUBLISHING_PROFILES\FIRECOM_LOCAL.pubxml 
/p:FrameworkPathOverride="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319" 
/p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0
```

After this I had another error with the Nuget Package and I had to remove the last target in my .csproj